# How to distinguish 2 endpoints with similar parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following API endpoints:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Find(FindParameters parameters)
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(GetParameters parameters)

public class GetParameters
{
   [NonDefault]
   public Guid GizmoId { get; set; }

   [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FindParameters : PagingParameters
{
    public Guid? GizmoId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Since they are expecting similar parameters I am running into the issue where I implement a get method but it ends up calling the Find endpoint.

I've played with the Order and that did not resolve my issue.

I've can get it to work by decorating the Get endpoint with

```
[HttpGet("Get", Order = 1)]
```

However, I would like to avoid that because I would no longer have a consistent convention across my all of APIs.

How can I set my endpoints so that when I implement a get it calls the Get endpoint and the find calls the Find endpoint?

Comment: These are different resources so shouldn't they have different endpoints?

Comment: They are different endpoints.  The issue is that either the Get end points always gets called or the Find.

Comment: How do these vary?  Would Find ultimately give the same result as Get for the same Id and Name?

Comment: Ok, sorry I should rephrase, since they are different resources, they should have different routes? e.g. `GET /FindParameters` and `GET /Parameters`? Bit difficult to expand without knowing more background on your requirements

Comment: Get should only return 1 where the Find could return 1 or many.

Comment: Why not just return one item in an array? A single endpoint should return a single data type to save yourself trouble such as the one you're facing now.

Comment: Then why does Get require a Name?  Is the Id not unique?

Comment: @Jamie For the Get I am trying to call the endpoint Gizmo\someId\Name\someName  and for the find it would be in the query string. Gimzo?gizmoid=xxx&name=yyy

Comment: @Juharr No it's the id to it's parent so there can be more then one.

Comment: could it be, that you did not specify the method name in the URL - so it uses a default endpoint. Does your URL consist of http://{Server}.com:8096/{Controller}/{Method(Get/Find)} ?

Comment: No our convention is for  Get  Controller/{param for get}   Find Controller?{query string parameters}